# Invoking Oracle stored function from Spring

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have an Oracle database and a stored function in it that has the following signature:

```
FUNCTION fnc_a_b1(pv_a10  IN VARCHAR2,
                          pn_b OUT NUMBER,
                          pv_c  OUT VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
```

There is a Java/Spring backend that should invoke this function and so far I have done the following:

```
public class MyStoredFunction extends StoredProcedure {

    public MyStoredFunction(final DataSource datasource) {
        super(datasource, "package_name.fnc_a_b1");
        setFunction(true);
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("pv_a10", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("pn_b", Types.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("pv_c", Types.VARCHAR));
        compile();
    }
}
```

I execute it like:

```
final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("pv_a10", "123123");
new MyStoredFunction(datasource).execute(params);
```

and I get

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FNC_A_B1'
```

Any idea why? Everything seems ok (sorry for the name obfuscation - digits in the names are actually present as well as the pv/pn prefixes but the ones from the db coincide with the ones in the backend)

Comment: Have you tried adding another out parameter, for the return value?

Comment: @Deroude, actually no (I'm very new to all of this). Adding another declareParameter for the return value fixed it. Post your comment as an answer if you'd like (and also thanks a lot for this!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns `VARCHAR2`. That's basically another OUT parameter. Adding it to your declarations should fix this.

```
declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("return_param", Types.VARCHAR));
```